# Tomcat returning 404 error while accessing servlet

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I have copied the WAR file I've exported by eclipse into the Webapp directory of tomcat then I rewrote the web.xml file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
 PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

<display-name>MMP</display-name>
<description>
</description>


<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>SignInValidment</servlet-name>
<description>This servlet plays the controller of the Placement Test proccess
</description>

<servlet-class>SignInValidment</servlet-class>

<load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>SignInValidment</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/SignInValidment</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>    <!-- 30 minutes -->
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

The problem is , when the program tries to access SignInValidment Servlet to validate the sign in event , Tomcat returns 404 error , that /MMP/SignInValidment/ not found and then I can't even access the root of project (jsp files)anymore, it keeps giving me this error : "HTTP Status 404 - " .

I'm using tomcat version 8.0 and note that my computer is a little infected with viruses and harmful programs.
I'm really in an emergency problem , please help me run this project.

Comment: Is SignInValidment in a package because if it is it should be like:  `<servlet-class>com.whatever.whatever.SignInValidment</servlet-class>`

Comment: Also what is your base url like: `http://localhost:8080/MMP`?

Comment: @brso05 I don't think they are in a package all of servlets including SignInValidment are in the classes folder in the WEB-inf , Yes it is like http://localhost://8080/MMP